# redirect local requests to ip to other ip (linux - e.g. debian >= 10)

Tags: linux, networking, routing, firewall, nftables

I want to all request to a certain IP:port on the machine A its self (for a current or rather 10/11/12) to another IP = machine B so that requests from processes on machine A are forwarded to machine B with IP B.

Machine A can reach the network of machine B and the other way round (`ip a` on machine A:

```
2: eno1: ...

    inet X.Y.52.60/24 brd X.Y.52.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet X.Z.52.16/24 brd X.Z.52.255 scope global eno1:1
```

I have tried diffeent approaches:

- `nftables`

```
      chain postrouting {
              type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
              masquerade
      }

      chain prerouting {
              type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
              ip daddr X.Y.52.69 tcp dnat to X.Z.10.99
      }
```

- `route add -net X.Y.52.60/32 gw X.Z.10.99` with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=`(which should redirect all ports)
  (* `iptables` - as there a lot of all manuals about this and command should be passed to the nftables wrapper. I did: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d X.Y.52.69 -p tcp --dport 31000 -j DNAT --to-destination X.Z.10.99`
  )

As far I know handling with  `socat`or `ssh` is not possible

With the firewall approach redirection seam to work nut nmap report filtered port. With `route`I got `SIOCADDRT: Invalid argument`.

Which one is the best approach and how does it actually work on current Linux systems?

Comment: Your `nft` postrouting nat rule is missing the destination IP that you want to masquerade as - maybe something like `nft add rule nat postrouting output ip daddr X.Z.10.99 snat to X.Y.52.69`. The rules you have currently only apply NAT in one direction which should fail. Don't use `route` for this, because it doesn't adjust the source IP. Take a look through the "Using NAT statements" section here for more info: https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html

Comment: `output` is generating a syntax error - I guess because following the manpage ` postrouting` is already the `hook`?. By the way: I rather want to route a whole subnet (/24) - is it just `add rule table_name postrouting ip daddr x.x.x.1/24 to y.y.y.1/24`?

Comment: Is there a reason Machine A has 2 IP addresses? Are you expecting one of these two addresses having a special role for your question? Also why is the NAT rule using a *third* IP address? X.Y.52.69 which is neither X.Y.52.60 nor X.Y.52.16. You'll have to explain this as well. And finally "As far I know handling with  socat ... is not possible". I'm quite sure socat can also handle this but nothing can be done until you explain the role of the *three* (not two nor one) IP addresses: I'd think there's a mistake or confusion with this.

Comment: Machine A has 2 ethernet interfaces but for this issues only one is relevant.
 `X.Y.52.69` is the IP of machine B. 
I will / would like to focus on `nftables` now.